# Function keys not working at Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, guake

I use <kbd>F12</kbd> key to open `guake` terminal. Whenever I press <kbd>F12</kbd> key it doesn't work. However, no function keys are working if I am at desktop or at file manager.

Is there any solution for it?

Thank you.

Comment: The title suggests this is a new development. Should we assume it didn't happen before with a different Ubuntu version or other OS?

Comment: @ChanganAuto , I was using ubuntu version 20.04 earlier and it was working there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason that it does not work is because Ubuntu now is running on Wayland instead of Xorg. One of the security measures of Wayland - which in fact is crippling functionality - is that applications are not anymore allowed to globally listen for shortcut keys.

Some applications cannot run on Wayland. For these, Wayland provides an emulation layer, xwayland. As long as an application running on xwayland is in the foreground, your function key will work. If a native Wayland application is in the foreground, your function key will not work.

There are two possible options

*Option 1*: Check whether Guake terminal provides a command line option to have it open/close. A very quick search learned me that there is an `-s` or `--show-hide` option. Remove the hotkey setting within the preferences of Quake itself, and instead create a shortcut in "Settings" - "Keyboard shortcuts" where you specify the command `guake -s`.

*Option 2*: Log in on an Xorg session instead. All will work as previously.

Comment: Great explanation. This is the kind of quirk I expected when switching to Wayland, but had no idea what exactly caused the change.

Comment: This also affects the hide_window shortcut of Terminator which will stop working. Thanks for the hint, I've found documentation about X11 but nothing mentioned Xorg.
See https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/427

Comment: Currently, the guake shortcut to use is `guake -t`.

Answer (score 5):

As say @vanadium in my case it was cleaning guake preferences for toggle shortcut and create a new one on gnome settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts and creates a shortcut for command `guake -t`

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/12/how-to-use-guake-terminal-under-wayland.html) gives a pretty simple solution (along with the same explanation as vanadium gave). It only requires you to add a custom shortcut in gnome's control panel that triggers the `guake-toggle` command.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a custom shortcut in gnome for `guake-toggle`